# How to parse unix timestamp into datetime without timezone in Fast API

Tags: python, python-datetime, fastapi, pydantic

Assume I have a pydantic model

```
class EventEditRequest(BaseModel):
    uid: UUID
    name: str
    start_dt: datetime
    end_dt: datetime
```

I send request with body `b'{"uid":"a38a7543-20ca-4a50-ab4e-e6a3ae379d3c","name":"test event2222","start_dt":1600414328,"end_dt":1600450327}'`

So both `start_dt` and `end_dt` are unix timestamps. But in endpoint they become datetimes with timezones.

```
@app.put('...')
def edit_event(event_data: EventEditRequest):
    event_data.start_dt.tzinfo is not None  # True
```

I don't want to manually edit `start_dt` and `end_dt` in the endpoint function to get rid of timezones. How can I set up my pydantic model so it will make datetime without timezones?

Comment: One solution I came to is to make middleware that will replace unix timestamp to datetime w/o timezone before it will become pydantic object. But it doesn't look the best solution to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use own [@validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) to parse `datetime` manually:

```
from datetime import datetime

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Model(BaseModel):
    dt: datetime = None


class ModelNaiveDt(BaseModel):
    dt: datetime = None

    @validator("dt", pre=True)
    def dt_validate(cls, dt):
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(dt)


print(Model(dt=1600414328))
print(ModelNaiveDt(dt=1600414328))
```

Output:

```
dt=datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 18, 7, 32, 8, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
dt=datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 18, 10, 32, 8)
```

Answer (score 6):

Like sashaaero mentions in their answer, you can achieve this with a custom type. But instead of creating your own validation, you could just use the existing validator from Pydantic and then just remove the timezone info.

```py
from pydantic.datetime_parse import parse_datetime


class OffsetNaiveDatetime(datetime):

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        v = parse_datetime(v)
        v = v.replace(tzinfo=None)
        return v
```

But be careful to only use it where timezone information is not needed at all or doesn't apply.

Answer (score 3):

One more way to achieve it is to create custom type

```
class UnixDatetime(datetime):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        if isinstance(v, datetime):
            print('Some request sends datetime not in UNIX format', file=sys.stderr)
            return v.replace(tzinfo=None)
        elif isinstance(v, int):
            return datetime.fromtimestamp(v)
        assert False, 'Datetime came of %s type' % type(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new Pydantic version 2, we can expand on [@Benedikt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6554216/benedikt-%C3%93skarsson)'s answer like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator

class ModelWithDate(BaseModel):
    dt: datetime = None

    @field_validator('dt')
    @classmethod
    def remove_timezone(cls, dt) -> datetime:
        return dt.replace(tzinfo=None)
```

Pydantic will first parse it into a regular `datetime` object before passing it to your validator, so you don't have to worry about handling various types like timestamps or strings, you can simply drop the `tzinfo` from the object.